# mvc4 lambda: Add separate query to object model?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have a query that pulls information about jobs:

```
    var jobs = db.jobs.Include(d => d.docs)
                      .Where(o => o.officeid == 2);
    return View(jobs.ToList());
```

This works great but, I also have to ADD the following query to it somehow, so that I can print an extra column of "word count" values onto the .cshtml page.

```
    SELECT SUM(docs.words) FROM docs 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN reviewer ON docs.reviewerid = reviewer.reviewerid 
    WHERE docs.docid = 1111 AND reveiwer.type = 'student'
```

So in a nutshell, all the jobs data in the first lambda query up top needs to print out in a table...BUT ALSO, the last query needs to be converted into lambda form and combined with the original lambda query so that each doc's word count is added to the jobs object model.

This is what I have but it is not working:

```
    var jobs = db.jobs.Include(d => d.docs)
                      .Include(r => r.docs)
                      .Sum(s => s.docs.words)
                      .Where(o => o.officeid == 2);
    return View(jobs.ToList());
```

What is the correct way to do this please?  Thanks much!

Comment: This became too frustrating to figure out so I just manually joined all the tables using linq's join keyword.  For the "word count" part, I re-used one of the columns already in the table and overwrote its values temporarily so that I could display them without having to add an extra column to the object.  Not a good solution but it works.  Thanks all for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
public class Job
{
    public List<Doc> Docs;
}

public class Doc
{
    public int Words;
}

List<Job> Jobs = new List<Job> { 
    new Job { Docs = new List<Doc> { new Doc { Words = 5 }, new Doc { Words = 10} } }, 
    new Job { Docs = new List<Doc> { new Doc { Words = 5 } } }
};

var res = Jobs.Select(x => new { Jobs = x, Cnt = x.Docs.Sum(y => y.Words) });
```

And create a ViewModel containing Jobs and their wordcount to send to your view instead of a List of objects.